# How to check, if S3 prefix corresponds to a file or folder?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have an S3 prefix. I want to find out, if it's a file or a whole folder. How do I do this with boto3?

Comment: S3 might give you an illusion that there is a folder structure, but it is essentially a key-value pair with a flat structure. It uses the `/` to provide that sort of view.
More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in a comment, there is no notion of directories in S3. You can find out if the object is a file by attempting to retrieve it, but in order to determine if it is a "directory", you would have to list all the objects in the bucket and determine if the provided value is a prefix to any of them. This may not be feasible for you depending on how many items exist (or can exist) in the bucket.